# How to enable OCSP support with Let's Encrypt and cert-manager (Kubernetes)?

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager, ocsp

I'm trying to achieve the same functionality offered by the [--must-staple parameter of certbot](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#certbot-command-line-options), in a Kubernetes context (with nginx ingress and cert-manager). Is there any parameter in cert-manager, so generated Let's Encrypt certificates include the *OCSP Must-Staple extension*?

My current ClusterIssue config, which is where the parameter should be placed (I guess)

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-production
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

Comment: I'm curious if you found a solution to this. I `enable-ocsp: 'true'` for the `ingress-nginx` controller which now returns `OCSP Response Status: SUCCESSFUL`, but I still get `OCSP Must-Staple: NOT SUPPORTED - Extension not found`.

Comment: I didn't, this issue is unfortunately still open